# Deploying Django App on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I've been following the heroku django tutorial at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django and I keep running into the following problem.
When I run `heroku open` and go to my app's website I always get an `Application Error`.  When I look at the logs I see the following lines:

```
2011-10-11T04:55:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python hellodjango/manage.py runserver`
2011-10-11T04:55:35+00:00 app[web.1]: python: can't open file 'hellodjango/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My `ProcFile` only contains `web: python hellodjango/manage.py runserver`.

Lastly, when I use the `foreman start` at the command line my django app runs fine locally.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Has your hellodjango directory added, committed to git, and been pushed to Heroku? You should be able to ensure this with:

```
git status
```

Additionally you can explore an isolated dyno instance that has all of your application code as well as config vars with:

```
heroku run bash
```

This should allow you to ensure the file is there and if you're able to run the same command in your Procfile you should see the same results to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Ultimately, I got it to work by changing the ProcFile to read   "worker: python hellodjango/manage.py runserver".  I guess I'm not really clear on what goes under web and what goes under worker in a ProcFile.

Comment: @randomletters  Don't do "worker: python hellodjango/manage.py runserver"  What you are doing is running the project off the developmental server.  This causes major cache buildup when run for a sustained period of time.  Not to mention, it will likely crash after a few hours in production. Let Heroku handle deployment for you!  Try using Fabric to push/deploy your code base and "heroku run" as CraigKerstiens suggested.